# Does deauthenticating MACs on AP affect non-deauthenticated MACs on the same AP?

Tags: authentication, router, mac-address, aircrack-ng

In my attempts to learn more about infosec, I have started a small initial project.

- [greedy-mac](https://github.com/m4ttclendenen/greedy-mac) on Github

A linux shell script that continously deauthenticates all MACs on a given AP except for the MAC of a USB wireless dongle (with packet injection capabilities) and also the wireless card of the computer running the script.

This will hopefully allow one machine (the one running the script) to surf the web without sharing bandwidth.

However I am curious as to whether all the deauthenticating of the other machines will affect the AP's ability to serve the machine wanting to surf the web. Let's say 5 MACs are in a loop continuously being deauthenticated while one is allowed to surf the web. Or let's say up to infinity, will there be a point where the interference could be noticed?

Any other issues that could hinder the desired result with this given scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interference will be noticed by the affected macs... because their internet will drop, and they just need Wireshark to figure out what is happening.
But your NIC (which i assume will not be deauthed) will not be affected by the deauthed clients.
This is because the deauth packets are sent to particular clients, and only they will respond with a re-authentication to the router, effectively jamming their connection